# Compare 3 SQL tables from 3 different databases in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to compare three tables from three different databases in SQL Server. Is this even possible?

I have 3 different data bases: prod, test1, test2. I have a tables with definitions called DEFINITIONS in each database. There are different values in each of the table depending on the database. My job is to compare all of these 3 tables and point the differences.

I was thinking about using the `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT` operators to show the differences or similarities between these 3 tables but I cannot find any information how to merge these 3 databases.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Yes, it's possible; objects can be referenced using 3 part naming (instead of 2 part naming). What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: So I have 3 different data bases: prod, test1, test2. I have a tables with definitions called DEFINITIONS in each database. There are different values in each of the table depending on the database. My job is to compare all of these 3 tables and point the differences.

Comment: Maybe  `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the tables, on their shared primary key (they have a shared key value, right?) and the you can use `CASE` expression to check if the values of the columns are the same in the table, or missing?

Comment: @Viktor, the details you added in comments belongs in the question so I added it. If the databases are on different servers, add that info to your question.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean is there a reason you've recently been putting what I can only interpret as "nonsense" in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using except / intersect...
Main idea:

```sql
-- This creates rows that exist in db1 but not in db2
select * from db1.dbo.table1 t
except
select * from db2.dbo.table2 t
union
-- This creates rows that exist in db2 but not in db1
select * from db2.dbo.table2 t
except
select * from db1.dbo.table1 t
-- Etc...
```

To get the simularities you change EXCEPT to INTERSECT

The problem with this solution is that one column difference will generate two missing rows, one from db1 and one from db2.

This can be solved by using FULL OUTER JOIN ON primary keys from both tables and just displays row values.
Something like:

```sql
select CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 'Missing in 1' WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 'Missing in 2' ELSE 'Both exists'
, t.*, t2.*
from db1.dbo.table1 t
FULL OUTER JOIN db2.dbo.table2 t2
  ON t2.ID = t.ID
```

Then you just need to format data for your usage.

A couple of caveats of these approaches:

- All tables must have same number / type of columns for EXCEPT SELECT * to work. Otherwise you need to choose which columns to match
- Collations of varchar fields should match between the two database tables, otherwise EXCEPT / INTERSECT will crash. You can solve it by "re-collating" the columns by using: SELECT ..., somevarcharcolumn COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

There is also tools for this in Visual Studio and probably other clients (schema and data compare) etc.

Excel has some nice functions for this too, if you load data with matching rows from each table, you can color the diffing fields by using VLOOKUP etc